# iOS iAd and Freemium inside the same app

Tags: ios

Yes, this is a mess. I'm working on a free app with InApp purchases inside that unlock certain parts of the app. Now, my superiors asked me also add iAds advertising.

My opinion is that the user experience and brand image would be seriously affected. No user will feel comfortable if he has to pay for access to certain parts of the application, if he is seeing further publicity.

I need outside opinions to show that this practice is not appropriate. I understand that you must choose a business model: either iAds or Freemium. Trying to merge the two seems commercial suicide.

Comment: Is it possible to include ads on only the free areas of the site? That may be a compromise

Comment: I've seen "pay to remove ads" as a feature many times.

Comment: I'm making an app with iAd. I have an IAP for a small price that removes the ads. I also have 3 different IAP that extends the possibilities of my app. If you purchase one of them, you're being "offered" the remove ads option. The idea is "no matter how much you pay, if you buy something, you don't deserve ads".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users dislike this practice indeed, as they are accustomed to "paid version has no ads" business models.

If you want to prove to your managers that users will be angry with this, search a bit around. I typed "apps which have ads in the paid version" into Google and the second result was [this forum thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1669445) which is a nice case study of users showing their attitude towards this practice. The second reply says simply

> Yes, and they're scumbags for doing it

and the rest goes on in this vein.

You could make a small study. Gather such information from around the web, and when you have the names of a few apps doing it, look up these apps in the app store. Calculate some good indicator of the damage, for example 1) the ratio of 1-star reviews to 5-star reviews for these apps, and 2) the percentage of 1-star reviews which complain of ads in the paid version. Find apps with similar functionality as a control group, and calculate the first number for them too.

You will end up with some info on how exactly the customers react, and your bosses should be able to take an informed decision on it. If you restrict yourself to 4-5 apps, the whole work is probably done in half a workday.

Note that, as the comments mentioned, restricting the ads to the free version and removing them in the paid version is a business model most people classify as fair and it doesn't cause negative reactions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. That's what I'm working now. Hope they listen to reasons.